# How does Consul's script(args) check run in my pod?

Tags: kubernetes, consul, health-check, consul-health-check

I deploy Coscul through helm-chart, and don't enable to inject sidecar.
Then I register service which has args check as below.

```
    {
      "name": "demo-svc",
      "Address": "demo-svc.default.svc.cluster.local",
      "port": 8080,
      "checks": [
        {
            "name": "args check",
            "args": ["/bin/ls", "/home"],
            "interval": "3s",
            "timeout": "1s"
        }
      ]
    }
```

And get Output

```
consul
```

This health check result is not as expected, it shows the folder that isn't in my pod, looks like the script just runs in Consul-server.

Can the Consul's arges check execute script in my pod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consul health checks are run within the context of the agent that is executing them. Script checks, like the one you provided, will be run by the Consul client/server agent.

If you want to run a health check against your pod, you need to configure a network-level health check (i.e., TCP, HTTP, gRPC, etc) so that the agent can communicate with your target service.